# Homotopic functions

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

**Let $X$ be a space and $f,g:X\rightarrow S^n$, s.t $f(x)\neq g(x)$ ( $f,g$ continuous) for all $x$. Show that they are homotopic.**

Can you give me any hints on how to start attacking this exercise? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. If n is even the map $x \rightarrow -x$ from $S^n$ to itself and the identity map satisfy the hypothesis of your post, but the degree of the first is $-1$ while the second has degree $1$ which means they are not homotopic.

If you want a brutally explicit counterexample let $n=0$ then there are only two possible maps that satisfy the hypothesis if $X$ is connected, the constant maps to the two points. Clearly they are not homotopic.

Comment: My professor said to change the hypothesis to $f(x)\neq -g(x)$. Is it true this way?

Comment: Yes, look at the answer by @cwine. The denominator is never zero because if $f,g$ are functions into the sphere, the only time the denominator could have magnitude zero is if $t=(1-t)$ because otherwise the sum would have nonzero magnitude. Then the new condition implies that even when $t=1-t$, the denominator is never 0.

Comment: @pritchard No, consider maps with the point as the domain. All maps being homotopic is equivalent to being path connected, so try to think of a counter example.

Answer (score 1):

Construct $H(x,t): X \to S^n, = \frac{tf(x) + (1-t)g(x)}{||tf(x) + (1-t)g(x) ||}$. Clearly $H$ is continuous since the denominator is always nonzero (by assumption $f \neq g$), and $H(x, 0)=g(x)$ and $H(x,1) = f(x)$.

Comment: I think this is the right track, but if $f(x) = -g(x)$ then for $t=\frac{1}{2}$ the denominator is $0$.

Comment: That's right. I think instead make it (t-1) and that should solve it.

Comment: No. See Connor Malin's answer.